# selecting first n rows in each group in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file with five columns (comma separated and sorted by group):

Data looks like this:

XXServer , XXServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.324 , 2020-04-08T08:20:52.163
XXServer , XXServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
XXServer , XXServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
XXServer , XXServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 408.214 , 2020-04-08T14:36:26.434
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.324 , 2020-04-08T08:20:52.163
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
YYServer , YYServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
YYServer , YYServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
ZZServer , ZZServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 408.214 , 2020-04-08T14:36:26.434
and so on...

1. Want to print the first 3 rows from each group. Grouping based on first column only.

XXServer , XXServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.324 , 2020-04-08T08:20:52.163
XXServer , XXServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
XXServer , XXServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966

blank line

YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 408.214 , 2020-04-08T14:36:26.434
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.324 , 2020-04-08T08:20:52.163
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966

blank line

ZZServer , ZZServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 408.214 , 2020-04-08T14:36:26.434

blank line

2. Want to print the first 3 rows from each group. Grouping based on first and second column combined.

XXServer , XXServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.324 , 2020-04-08T08:20:52.163
XXServer , XXServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966

blank line

XXServer , XXServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
XXServer , XXServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966

blank line

YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 408.214 , 2020-04-08T14:36:26.434
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.324 , 2020-04-08T08:20:52.163
YYServer , YYServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966

blank line

YYServer , YYServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966
YYServer , YYServer_2 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 201.828 , 2020-04-08T08:20:54.966

blank line

ZZServer , ZZServer_1 , /ws/GenericSoapPort , 408.214 , 2020-04-08T14:36:26.434

blank line

The blank line is a group separator line that needs to be inserted at end of each group. A group may not have 3 rows - a condition that needs to be taken care of.

I know how to use groups when using group functions like sum, max, min etc. This one I just do not know, must be simple, but not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your second example is wrong and there should be a break (blank line) between YYServer,YYServer_1 and YYServer,YYServer_2:

```
 awk -F, '$1!=p {if(p)print ""; p=$1; l=NR+2} NR<=l; END {print ""}'

 awk -F, '$1!=p1||$2!=p2 {if(p1)print ""; p1=$1; p2=$2; l=NR+2} NR<=l; END {print ""}'
 # or
 awk -F, '$1","$2!=p {if(p)print ""; p=$1","$2; l=NR+2} NR<=l; END {print ""}'
```

Comment: Never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks a ton. The three commands work as desired. Also you were right about I missing the blank line. I have corrected it in the question.